# LIMIT amount of rows fetched by JOIN

Tags: mysql, greatest-n-per-group

How do i LIMIT the child rows fetched to only 5?

Here is the SQLfiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bd96a/2.  Right now it fetches all rows with `parentid='4'` and `parentid='14'`.  It should only fetch 5 of each parentid.  Assuming i have hundreds of rows, it should only fetch a max of 5 for each `parentid`.

```
 "SELECT child.* FROM mytable as parent
     LEFT JOIN mytable as child on child.parentid=parent.id
     WHERE parent.pageid IN ( 1, 2) AND parent.submittype='1'
     ORDER BY child.id ASC";
```

How do i solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the greatest n per group.. This will do what you want. Sorry I'm on my phone so I can't format it.. If someone could edit it for me that would be great!

```
SELECT 
    child.*, 
    if(@a = child.parentid, @b :=@b+1, @b := 1) as counting_col, 
    @a := child.parentid
FROM mytable as parent
LEFT JOIN mytable as child on child.parentid=parent.id
CROSS JOIN(select @a :=0, @b:=1) t
WHERE parent.pageid IN ( 1, 2) 
  AND parent.submittype='1'
HAVING counting_col <=5
ORDER BY child.id ASC
```

Comment: Thanks, do you mind explaining what the variables do?  I haven't used variables in mysql before.

Comment: So the variables check the value and increment when you have duplicate parentid's so then you add the having clause to say limit of each parentis by 5. Its hard to explain and or write queries with my phone.. I would have added a sqlfiddle but I can't copy the link if you run the query you will see what the counting_col does with the variables :) its pretty cool

Comment: @user892134 Another note you can put this in a sub query if you don't want to pull out the variables in the select.. Let me know and I can add that if you prefer it

Comment: Thanks, id like to see the subquery version.  Do you know any tutorials on variables in mysql? Even though you explained i'm having trouble following the query.

Comment: Basically I'm assigning one variable to the value of the parentid... Then check for that value.. The order is the key. So I say if the Id is the same as the variable then increment the other variable. If they aren't the same then reset my counter variable to 1.. After this I then set the first variable @a to the parentid on that row... The reason why is because on the next row your variable will be equal to the previous row... Until you reset it to that parentid if that makes sense

Comment: What is the cross join for?

Comment: You could do the same thing with a join or left join or whatever.. Its just creating the variables with a default value

Comment: Thanks you've been a great help.  The only thing i'm having trouble grasping is `Cross join(select @a :=0, @b:=1) t` .  Creating variables with a default value?  I don't understand what that means.

Comment: Yes it just initializes those variables with a value

Comment: Ok i understand.  I thought the variables were initialized in the If statement.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: In the Cross Join, I know it sets the variables default value but why the `select`?  Does the `select` make the variables global?

Comment: Is the Cross Join even needed, i removed it and the query still works?

Comment: Keep it in there.. If you don't then running the query multiple times will mess it up. Because the variable doesn't get reset

Comment: The select is how you make them.. There isn't a global or non global in SQL its just a variable in memory